# Magento 2: Place an Order Checkout button popup box

Tags: magento2.2, popup, modal-popup

Merry Christmas everyone.

I have a question guys can you please teach me how to add a popup or modal upon clicking the "Place an Order" Button on the checkout page?

Just correct me if I'm wrong thanks.

Here's some screenshot

[image]

And this is the popup box that will appear after clicking place an order.

[image]

Comment: This can done. but need to do some code

Comment: Yes, I already have an extension on this one. But that's my problem with adding a popup modal once you click the place an order button on the checkout page.

Comment: do you need the code for sending and verifying the code as well or just showing pop up on placing order and on Clicking verify go to Place order.

Comment: Hello Anime. I just need a code for showing a pop up upon placing order. Thanks

Comment: @MazeStricks how you DONE this. can you share your code for popup ?

Comment: @SURENDERSINGH I haven't done this popup one. That's my problem to create something like that.

Comment: i need someone help for setup the model popup when user click on place order button. Thanks

Comment: Hi Could you tell me name of this module?

Comment: @MazeStricks, have you done it, I need the same requirement for mobile verification before place order.